SwiftUI: View potentially being cached when it has a binding with the previous view that navigates to this view
I have two views: ContentView and AnnotationView.
The ContentView has a navigationDestination that leads to the AnnotationView, which isPresented when a certain property is true.
Here is the source code of the ContentView (can probably ignore CameraManager for this problem)
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import Vision
import Metal
import CoreImage
import MetalKit

// TODO: Make this a class variable instead of a global variable
var annotationView: Bool = false

class SharedImageData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cameraImage: UIImage?
    @Published var depthData: CVPixelBuffer?
//    @Published var depthDataImage: UIImage?
    
    @Published var pixelBuffer: CIImage?
//    @Published var objectSegmentation: CIImage?
//    @Published var segmentationImage: UIImage?
    
    @Published var segmentedIndices: [Int] = []
    // Single segmentation image for each class
    @Published var classImages: [CIImage] = []
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var selection: [Int]
    
    @StateObject private var sharedImageData = SharedImageData()
    @State private var manager: CameraManager?
    @State private var navigateToAnnotationView = false
    var objectLocation = ObjectLocation()
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if manager?.dataAvailable ?? false{
                    ZStack {
                        HostedCameraViewController(session: manager!.controller.captureSession)
                        HostedSegmentationViewController(sharedImageData: sharedImageData, selection: Array(selection), classes: Constants.ClassConstants.classes)
                    }
                    Button {
                        annotationView = true
                        objectLocation.settingLocation()
                        manager!.startPhotoCapture()
                        // TODO: Instead of an arbitrary delay, we should have an event listener to the CameraManager
                        // that triggers when the photo capture is completed
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
                            navigateToAnnotationView = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "camera.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    VStack {
                        SpinnerView()
                        Text("Camera settings in progress")
                            .padding(.top, 20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $navigateToAnnotationView) {
                AnnotationView(sharedImageData: sharedImageData, objectLocation: objectLocation, 
                               selection: sharedImageData.segmentedIndices, classes: Constants.ClassConstants.classes,
                               navigateToAnnotationView: $navigateToAnnotationView
                )
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Camera View", displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear {
                print("Is Manager Nil \(self.manager == nil)")
                if (manager == nil) {
                    manager = CameraManager(sharedImageData: sharedImageData)
                } else {
                    // TODO: Need to check if simply resuming the stream is enough
                    //  or do we have to re-initialize some other properties
                    manager?.resumeStream()
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                manager?.stopStream()
            }
            .onChange(of: navigateToAnnotationView) { newNavigateToAnnotationView in
                if (!newNavigateToAnnotationView && (manager != nil)) {
                    manager?.resumeStream()
                }
            }
    }
}

The AnnotationView, as mentioned, has a binding to the property navigateToAnnotationView.
Here is the code for the AnnotationView:
import SwiftUI
struct AnnotationView: View {
    @ObservedObject var sharedImageData: SharedImageData
    @State private var index = 0
    
    let options = ["I agree with this class annotation", "Annotation is missing some instances of the class", "The class annotation is misidentified"]
    @State private var selectedOptionIndex: Int? = nil
    
    var objectLocation: ObjectLocation
    var selection: [Int]
    var classes: [String]
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @Binding var navigateToAnnotationView: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if (!self.isValid()) {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                .onAppear() {
                    print("AnnotationView isValid 1 \(self.selection.isEmpty), \(index) vs \(self.selection.count)")
                    navigateToAnnotationView = false
                    self.dismiss()
                }
        } else {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        HostedAnnotationCameraViewController(sharedImageData: sharedImageData, index: index)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Selected class: \(classes[selection[index]])")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    ProgressBar(value: calculateProgress())
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(0..<options.count, id: \.self) { optionIndex in
                                Button(action: {
                                    // Toggle selection
                                    if selectedOptionIndex == optionIndex {
                                        selectedOptionIndex = nil
                                    } else {
                                        selectedOptionIndex = optionIndex
                                    }
                                }) {
                                    Text(options[optionIndex])
                                        .padding()
                                        .foregroundColor(selectedOptionIndex == optionIndex ? .red : .blue) // Change color based on selection
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        objectLocation.calcLocation(sharedImageData: sharedImageData, index: index)
                        self.nextSegment()
                        selectedOptionIndex = nil
                    }) {
                        Text("Next")
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Annotation View", displayMode: .inline)
            .onAppear {
                print("AnnotationView isValid 2 \(self.selection.isEmpty), \(index) vs \(self.selection.count)")
                if (!self.isValid()) {
                    navigateToAnnotationView = false
                    self.dismiss()
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: index) { _ in
                // Trigger any additional actions when the index changes
                self.refreshView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func isValid() -> Bool {
        if (self.selection.isEmpty || (index >= self.selection.count)) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func nextSegment() {
        self.index += 1
    }

    func refreshView() {
        // Any additional refresh logic can be placed here
        // Example: fetching new data, triggering animations, sending current data etc.
    }

    func calculateProgress() -> Float {
        return Float(self.index) / Float(self.selection.count)
    }
}

The attempt in the AnnotationView is that if isValid() returns false, then I immediately navigate back to the ContentView.
While this seems to work, the problem I am facing is that when I click the button on ContentView again, the 'new' AnnotationView that opens, still retains the state variable values as the previous instance of the AnnotationView.
Inline EDIT: Example, the index state variable. It is supposed to be initialized as 0.
Suppose, I trigger the nextSegment() method of the AnnotationView once. The value of index becomes 1. Then let's say, I navigate back to the ContentView, and then navigate to the AnnotationView again. In such a case, I'd expect to get a new instance of AnnotationView, where the value of index is 0. But the value of index remains 1 in this scenario.
This does not seem to happen when I get rid of the navigateToAnnotationView binding. However, when I do that, the back navigation to the ContentView does not work properly, as neither the onAppear nor the onChange get triggered.
May I know what may be going on with the binding? Is the AnnotationView getting cached for performance?

where does sharedImageData comes from? Are you using the deprecated NavigationView or NavigationStack?

Ah apologies. This comes from the ContentView itself, but I was trimming down the function to cause less confusion as the views are quite big.

Let me just add the non-trimmed code instead.

Done. I have added the non-trimmed code

What do you mean by "still retains the same state variables as the previous instance of the AnnotationView"? Exactly which state variables remain the same?

The index state variable value does not get re-initialized to 0, when I re-navigate to AnnotationView. I have given more details in the inline edit in the post.
